# IE and Visual Studio are erroring on different page than it is showing on the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug a page, and it is telling me the Javascript function doesn't exist.  However when I debug in VS, the name of the page is Overview.aspx and it shows the code for EditStates.aspx that points to a function in EditStates.js saying it can't find the Javascript function.

Fiddler shows no calls to Overview.*

IE, loads the content for EditStates.aspx on screen, but F12 still shows the code for Overview.aspx.

When I move from Overview.aspx to EditStates.aspx I call

```
    protected void btn_edit_states_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ACIG.WebFunctions.ChangePage(Session, Response, Context, "/Notices/EditStates.aspx?mgi=" + ddlbGroup.SelectedItem.Value, "Overview.aspx");
    }
```

The code for ChangePage is:

```
        public static void ChangePage(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState Session, HttpResponse Response, HttpContext Context, string url, string PageName)
        {
            Session["ThrowBackPage"] = PageName;
            Response.Redirect(url, false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

In EditStates.aspx the Save button code is:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btn_save" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="button startHidden" OnClientClick="ClientSave_1();" OnClick="btn_save_Click"/>
```

In EditStates.js I have:

```
function ClientSave_1() {
    $(".changed").removeClass('changed');
    return true; }
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Although restarting the application and Visual Studios multiple times did nothing, rebooting the computer entirely seems to have fixed this.

Thanks,
Rick